# Authentication for the Firebase Cloud Function-based API with API key and OAuth - getting the uid in from the request

Tags: firebase, rest, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on the custom express API based on the single Cloud Function and I'd like to secure the endpoints with the authentication. I'm aiming for implementing the API key flow and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow. In my endpoint functions I'd need to obtain the user id somehow and I was wandering how can I archive that. Should I mix Firebase Token (createCustomToken) with these auth flows?  e.g in the API key flow when user generates a new token on the frontend then on the backend I should create a Firebase Token instead of custom hashed token and store it in db?

Any ideas how to do it properly, maybe are there any other/better ways to retrieve the uid?

Comment: Taken a look at the provided [Firebase Authentication + Cloud Functions for Firebase + Express](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/539345b1d7b3af7a7fd4fadaa54255329bdff3e3/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71) sample?

Comment: @samthecodingman yes, but still I'd like to have the complete OAuth 2.0 and API key flows and I'm not sure how to mix them with the firebase token id

Comment: Are you using the OAuth token of another service to authenticate your API ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential)) or are you trying to host your own OAuth service for your application on Cloud Functions?

Comment: I'm trying the custom one with [express-oauth-server](https://github.com/oauthjs/express-oauth-server)

Comment: my current understanding and aimed approach are to store API tokens/keys in the firestore collection along with the userId (which I will get during the token generation) and obtain it in the requests by querying the token doc which matches the current provided one. But I'm not sure if it's the best and proper way.

Comment: My main concern would be securing the database that you are storing the secrets you issue to clients in and also ensuring that your API responses are never cached. You could store the client ID and secret in Firebase Auth as the username (append something like `@apps.myapp.com`) and password respectively and attach a custom claim with the original user's ID. Then whenever a token exchange happens, you can feed it to the REST API and return the Firebase ID token and refresh token. This thread is tricky as it has too many variables involved which doesn't fit StackOverflow's Q&A format very well.